# How to load CSV/Excel to Google Cloud MySQL or google cloud buckets?

Tags: mysql, excel, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

What could be the best possible way to Load a CSV/Excel file to a Google Cloud MYSQL or Google Cloud Bucket.

Else Can someone suggest on a easy way to create a CSV to SQL Dump.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud SQL has an CSV import function. Check out the guide at: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#importing_csv_files_to_title_short